# Solving a diffusion-convection type linear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I have the following PDE for a function $u(t,x,y)$ defined for $t,x,y>0$:
$$
2\partial_tu=x\partial_{xx}u+\sqrt{xy}\partial_{xy}u+\frac y2\partial_{yy}u+2\rho\partial_xu+\rho\partial_yu
$$
where $\rho>1$ is a constant.

Is it possible to solve this equation explicitly?

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: The domain is $x>0,y>0$. The initial condition is $u(0,x,y)=f(x,y)$.

Comment: You'll probably want to try a Laplace transform then. You can also somewhat simplify your problem by setting $x \to x + \rho t, y \to y + \rho t/ 2$ so that your PDE becomes $$2u_{t} = x u_{xx} + \sqrt{xy} u_{xy} + \frac{y}{2} u_{yy}$$

Comment: Thank you! I am just thinking about how the $\sqrt{xy}$ term can fit nicely in a Laplace transform...

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the simplification. My mappings don't simplify the problem at all due to the non constant coefficients which I forgot to take into account. You'll just have to LT the original PDE.

Comment: How do you LT a PDE with non-constant coefficients?